# Why does S3 bucket ARN not contain AWS account number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Unlike other AWS services, s3 resources, ARN does not contain AWS account number. 
Few sample ARNs are:

- -- Elastic Beanstalk application version -- 
     arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:123456789012:environment/My
       App/MyEnvironment
- -- IAM user name -- 
     arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/David
- -- Amazon RDS instance used for tagging -- 
      arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:123456789012:db:mysql-db

On the other hand s3 bucket ARN looks like:

- arn:aws:s3:::my_corporate_bucket/exampleobject.png

Answer (score 29, accepted):

S3 Bucket ARNs do not require an account number or region since bucket names are unique across all accounts/regions.

Comment: Correct. To expand on this... Since bucket names are unique, the bucket name can be used by AWS to determine the Region and Account. This is different to other services such as Amazon SQS, where the same queue name could be used in different accounts and even in the same account in different regions.

Comment: While not necessary, is it possible to get a full ARN that includes the account?

Comment: @MelissaGuo I do not think there is any way, but if you are trying to restrict access e.g. managing user permissions, you could do something like `arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/developers/${aws:username}/` and use Cognito/IAM. There are some examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html) but I guess it depends on your use case.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo, what if I want to write a policy that gives access to all s3 buckets in a specific account, but I don't want to grant access to all s3 buckets in all accounts?  

I.e., I want something like:  `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3::<accountid>:*"`

not:  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"

Answer (score 4):

The question is "Why does S3 bucket ARN not contain AWS account number?" and the answer to that is because S3 was the first AWS service to be launched and many things have changed since then. S3 hasn't managed yet to implement the ARN in the bucket name. We don't know why that is. It could be that it's technically challenging or that it's just not being prioritized by the service team.

One way to validate that the bucket objects are being uploaded to belongs to you to avoid accidental data leak to other people's buckets is to use the recently released bucket owner condition:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-s3-bucket-owner-condition-helps-validate-correct-bucket-ownership
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-owner-condition.html

Another way (where supported) is to use S3 Access Points: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/access-points/

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this, however, is that it is not possible to write a policy that restricts actions only on a bucket in my account. The risk being that some user in my account may leak data out by pushing data to another account’s bucket.

Comment: Using an IAM condition allowed me to limit the scope of * to just the buckets in a single account. "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:ResourceAccount": "999999999999"}}

Answer (score 0):

**S3** buckets are designed to have globally unique names primarily to facilitate a flat namespace across the entire AWS S3 service. This uniqueness ensures that every bucket name is distinct and prevents naming conflicts across different AWS accounts and regions.

**The global uniqueness of bucket names is essential for several reasons:**

**Scalability and Accessibility**: S3 is a highly scalable service with a massive number of users. Having globally unique bucket names allows AWS to manage an extensive network of buckets efficiently.

**Simple Access**: It simplifies the process of accessing resources. Since bucket names are unique globally, you can reference a specific bucket without worrying about name conflicts or ambiguity.

**URL Structure**: S3 bucket names are used in the URL structure for accessing objects stored within the bucket. The unique names help form a clear and unambiguous URL hierarchy.

**DNS-based Access**: AWS uses DNS to route requests to the appropriate S3 buckets. Global uniqueness ensures that the DNS resolution for bucket names can be straightforward and unambiguous.

While this requirement for unique bucket names can sometimes pose a challenge when creating new buckets, it's a necessary aspect of the design to maintain the scalability and accessibility of the S3 service across different AWS accounts and regions.